# Radon Nikodym derivative of Lebesgue-continuous distribution wrt Lebesgue + singular at 0 base distribution.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue measure, and $\zeta$ denote the measure with $\zeta(A)=1$ if $0 \in A$ and $\zeta(A)=0$ otherwise, i.e. $\zeta$ is a point mass at zero. Now let $\nu = \mu + \zeta$, that is, $\nu(A)$ is defined as $\mu(A)+\zeta(A)$.

Let $F$ be some probability distribution absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure $\mu$. I would like to determine $\frac{dF}{d\nu}$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $F$ with respect to $\nu$.

Here is my attempt:

Since $F(A) = \int_{A} \frac{dF}{d\nu} d\nu$ and $F(\{0\})=0=\int_{\{0\}} \frac{dF}{d\nu}d\nu = \int_{\{0\}} \frac{dF}{d\nu}d\zeta$, it must be that $\frac{dF}{d\nu}(0) = 0$.

Furthermore, for $A$ such that $0\notin A$, $F(A) = \int_{A} \frac{dF}{d\nu} d\nu = \int_{A} \frac{dF}{d\nu} d\mu$, so we must have that $\frac{dF}{d\nu}=\frac{dF}{d\mu}$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $A$.

Therefore, I conclude that $\frac{dF}{d\nu}(x) = \frac{dF}{d\mu}(x)$ for almost all (wrt $\mu$) nonzero $x$ and $\frac{dF}{d\nu}(0)=0$.

In other words, the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $F$ wrt $\nu$ is the same as the RN derivative wrt $\mu$, except with a hole at zero.

Is this the correct result? If so, is my proof rigorous? If so, is there a better way of looking at things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct and your proof is rigorous.

To see this, note that for any set $A$ such that $0 \notin A$, we have

$$F(A)=
\int_A
​
 fdF=
\int_A
​
 fdμ,$$

On the other hand, we have

$$F({0})=
\int_0
​
 fdF=\int_0
​
 fdν,$$

but since $\nu({0})=1$ and $\mu({0})=0$, we have $d\nu/d\mu=1_{{0}}$ (i.e., the indicator function of ${0}$), so

$$
\int_0
​
 fdν=f(0) 
\int_{0}
​
 1 _
{0}
​
 dμ=0,$$

since $\mu({0})=0$. Therefore, $dF/d\nu$ has a hole at $0$, as you stated.